# Django signals creates for the same model

Tags: django

I am trying to make a signal that creates a Client object or Director object depending on the type of the CustomUser:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    TYPE = (
        (0, 'Client'),
        (1, 'Director'),

    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=TYPE)


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)


class Director(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)


def post_save_data(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and CustomUser.objects.get(email=instance.email).type == 0:
        Client.objects.create(user=instance)
    elif created and CustomUser.objects.get(email=instance.email).type == 1:
        Director.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(post_save_data, sender=CustomUser)
```

Whatever i do it always creates object for Client, even if i choose type 1.

Comment: Can you post your `AbstractEmailUser` class? And what if you change the `type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=TYPE)`, does it create director then?

Comment: There is error here: `TYPE = ((0, 'Client'), (1, 'Director'),`. You need to add the closing `)` like `TYPE = ((0, 'Client'), (1, 'Director'),)`.

Comment: Yea but that's not the problem

Comment: I'll post the AbstractEmail when i get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following code and from django admin if I create Custom user by selecting Client, it creates client and if select Director it creates Director.

```
class AbstractEmailUser(models.Model):
    email = models.TextField(max_length=100)


class CustomUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    TYPE = (
        (0, 'Client'),
        (1, 'Director'),
    )

    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=TYPE)


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)


class Director(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)


def post_save_data(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # if created and CustomUser.objects.get(email=instance.email).type == 0:
    #     Client.objects.create(user=instance)
    # elif created and CustomUser.objects.get(email=instance.email).type == 1:
    #     Director.objects.create(user=instance)
    if created:
        c_user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=instance.email)
        print(c_user.type)
        if c_user.type == 0:          
            Client.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif c_user.type == 1:
            Director.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(post_save_data, sender=CustomUser)
```

The commented code above on `post_save_data` also worked for me. I have used `AbstractEmailUser` class as a sample.